# How can I change the Color of eclipse search console

Tags: windows-7, eclipse

How can I change the colors of the eclipse search console?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/39RqPGj.png]

Specifically I'd like to change the background color of the highlight of the selected item

Comment: @magicandre1981 thanks for the edit. I don't have enough reputation to embed pics

Answer (score 0):

Open Preferences, and navigate to General->Editors->Text Editors->Annotations.  Select Occurrences, and change the color to whatever you like..

Comment: thanks, but changing the color of Occurrences does not change the colors of the search console, only the highlighted occurrences in the editor

Answer (score 0):

To set the highlight colour for *matching text* in the Search window, i.e. the purple highlight in the image:

Under Preferences->General->Colors and Fonts, select "Match background highlight" and edit/reset the colour.

Comment: I realise this is an older question, but I was looking for something similar and google led me here, so this is for anyone in the same boat.

Comment: was slightly different in my setup, had to go to window->Preferences->General->Appearance->Colora and Fonts and then in the window edit the match highlighting color under the Text Search section